# Delete request using guzzle in laravel not working

Tags: rest, api, laravel-5, guzzle, guzzle6

I am developing an API using resource controller in laravel. To call this api from my client i am using guzzle(my client is also laravel). For POST and GET requests it worked fine but for delete request it is showing below error.
[image]

My delete request is

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->delete('http://localhost:8017/opendemo_old/public/TestAPI/123456');
```

Below are my post and get request which are working fine.

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost:8017/opendemo_old/public/TestAPI', [
        'form_params' => [
            'field_name' => 'abcddd',
            'other_field' => '12344',
            'nested_field' => [
                'nested' => 'hello'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8017/opendemo_old/public/TestAPI/123'); <br/>
```

I am not getting what's the problem with delete request. I am using guzzle 6 and laravel 5.2(client & server).

Comment: Your API is returning a 500 error. There is something wrong with the delete route logic, not the client calling it.

Comment: @DavidBarker thanks for your comment. currently i did'nt wrote any logic in delete route it is under testing. actually it's an resource controller and the delete method is `public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
        echo "Delete";
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to **DELETE** request for **Laravel**.

```php
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->post('http://localhost:8017/opendemo_old/public/TestAPI/123456', [
    'form_params' => [
        '_method' => 'DELETE'
    ]
]);
```